# Как получить подробные свойства файлов в Powershell такие как размер изображения или длину аудиофайла?

Tags: windows, файлы, изображения, аудио, powershell

Стоит задача получать полные свойства файлов в папке и выводить их в отдельный .txt
Из всего что смог найти в интернете это использовать командлет Get-Childitem и выводить все атрибуты объекта с типом Property.
Сейчас это выглядит так:

```
Get-Childitem $File | Format-List -Property * | Out-File -FilePath $CreationFullName
```

Но в этом выводе не достаточно свойств, там выводятся только основные такие как вес или расположение файла. Хочется как-то получать более подробные свойства, которые сам Windows при клике по свойствам файла выводит во вкладке подробно, для картинок там пишется разрешение и глубина цвета, для аудио есть информация о длинне звуковой дорожки исполнитель и много еще всякого разного.
Подскажите как можно получить эти данные при помощи Powershell

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1240555/command-line-to-return-image-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге смог найти достаточные сведения для того чтобы решить поставленную задачу. Очень помог комментарий Алексея, нашел с какой стороны начинать копать. В результате понадобилось использовать метод GetDetailsOf. Почитать о том как его использовать можно [Тут](https://shellgeek.com/powershell-getdetailsof-file-in-folder/)
В результате стащил необходимые строчки из функции Get-FileMetaData. И подправил под свои потребности, в результате смог получить скрипт который вытаскивает метаданные последнего измененного файла. И сохраняет их в текстовый файл рядом. Скрипт не идеален, но функционал который от него нужен выполняет.

```
$TargetFolder = "C:\main"
$LastUpdateFile = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -File -Recurse | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1
$LastTimeUpdatedFileChanget = $LastUpdateFile.LastWriteTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
$LastTimeUpdatedFile = $LastTimeUpdatedFileChanget
$NameOfFile = $LastUpdateFile.Name
$NameOfDeroctory = $LastUpdateFile.DirectoryName
$objshell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$folderObject = $objshell.NameSpace($NameOfDeroctory)
$fileObject = $folderObject.ParseName($NameOfFile)
$folderObject.GetDetailsOf($fileObject,1)
$a = 0
for ( $a ; $a  -le 266; $a++ )
{ 
     if( $folderObject.getDetailsOf( $fileObject, $a ))
     {
           $InfoAboutFile += @{ $( $folderObject.getDetailsOf( $folderObject.items, $a ))  =
           $( $folderObject.getDetailsOf( $fileObject, $a )) }
     } 
}  
$DirectoryLastUpdateFile = $LastUpdateFile.DirectoryName
$NameUpdateFile = $LastUpdateFile.BaseName
$CreationFullName = "$($DirectoryLastUpdateFile)\$($NameUpdateFile).changed.txt"
$InfoAboutFile | Out-File -FilePath $CreationFullName
$InfoAboutFile.clear()
```